# Maven How to specify a directory of sql files for create-schema command

Tags: java, mysql, maven, configuration

I have a couple directories containing multiple sql files.  How can I configure maven to run all sql files in a directory.  My current config is like this:

```
      <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sql-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql-connector.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <driver>${mysql.jdbc.driver.class.name}</driver>
                <url>${mysql.jdbc.url}</url>
                <username>${mysql.jdbc.username}</username>
                <password>${mysql.jdbc.password}</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-schema</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${mysql.db.skip}</skip>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <srcFiles>
<srcFile>src/main/resources/directory1/file1.sql</srcFile>
<srcFile>src/main/resources/directory1/file2.sql</srcFile>
<srcFile>src/main/resources/directory2/file1.sql</srcFile>
<srcFile>src/main/resources/directory2/file2.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

There are many files in each directory.

How can use directories instead of listing each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/usage.html), instead of listing your files individually you can specify a fileset. An example of which is given [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html)

Answer (score 0):

Complete basedir  in pom.xml

```
 <execution>
        <id>create-data</id>
        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
          <fileset>
            <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
            <includes>
              <include>src/test/sql/test-data2.sql</include>
              <include>src/test/sql/test-data1.sql</include>
            </includes>
          </fileset>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```